# Call PHP Function from href with args to zip folder and download

Tags: php, html

Hello I have been searching a lot on stackoverflow and found tons of great info, bits and pieces of answers but still missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am fairly new to web development.

Basically what I am trying to accomplish is I have a button that when clicked I need it to zip a local folder and prompt to allow file download.

The button will need to pass 2 variables to the PHP function which are the directory to zip, and the zipped filename.

So far this is what I have.

File 1 with Button: (/var/www/html/index.php)

```html
<?php
// Directory to zip.
$dn = 'logs/report1';

// Zip filename.
$zn = 'report.zip';

echo <a class="btn btn-primary" style="color: white" onclick="location.href=logs/download.php?zipd='.$dn.'&zipn='.$zn'">Download</a>;
?>
```

File 2 PHP Download Function: (/var/www/html/logs/download.php)

```html
<?php
$zipd = $_GET['zipd'];
$zipn = $_GET['zipn'];


// Get real path for our folder
$rootPath = realpath($zipd);

// Initialize archive object
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($zipn, ZipArchive::CREATE | ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);


$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
 new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($rootPath),
 RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
);

foreach ($files as $name => $file)
{
 // Skip directories (they would be added automatically)
 if (!$file->isDir())
 {
     // Get real and relative path for current file
     $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
     $relativePath = substr($filePath, strlen($rootPath) + 1);

     // Add current file to archive
     $zip->addFile($filePath, $relativePath);
 }
}

// Zip archive will be created only after closing object
$zip->close();


// http headers for zip downloads
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$zipn."\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($zipd.$zipn));
ob_end_flush();
@readfile($zipd.$zipn);
?>
```

Comment: PHP can't access a local system. You will need to send all files you want zipped to the server.

Comment: Also, be careful because this is terribly insecure. A user could post an arbitrary pathname and download all of your secret files.

Comment: PHP of course can access the local system, it is sitting on the local system. I was hoping to find a cleaner way than shell_exec(). Any ideas of a cleaner way?